# ASP.NET MVC Ajax ActionLink - параметры из Input Hidden

Tags: ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день, друзья. Хочу узнать как грамотно решить следующую задачу:

На странице есть два блока: один условно "папки", вторая часть условно "файлы". Навигация по папкам осуществляется с помощью аякса и эта часть реализована. Там где файлы есть кнопка "отправить в текущую папку" (ту, которую выбрана и открыта сейчас).

Вопрос: как получить\передать методу `MoveToFolder(int ID_Folder, int ID_File)`. Переменные назвал для облегчения понимания ситуации, в проекте всё по-другому, конечно. `ID_File` - есть, а как получать `ID_Folder`, если навигация осуществляется динамически без перезагрузки страницы?

Вариант хранить текущий `ID_Folder` в сессии\кукисах не подходит, т.к. могут быть открыты две разные страницы с разными папками, соответственно. Получается, что только `<input type="hidden" />`. Вот вопрос, как засунуть в `Ajax.ActionLink` параметры из input hidden?

Скорее всего никак, т.к. страница генерируется ДО того, как аяксом мы выбираем папку :) Тогда как? Может через `OnBegin` как-то? Или единственный способ "ручками" через jQuery проводить запрос и там уже получить значение с hidden value? Единственный способ?

---

Нашёл решение, на мой взгляд весьма костыльное (как для чувака с 11к репутацией): https://stackoverflow.com/a/15104152/4727475

Ищу дальше.

UPD.

Данное решение - не работает для ActionLink - OnBegin срабатывает, но URL сохраняется и меняется уже после того, как отправляется аякс-запрос. Увы, малой кровью не обойтись( Придётся рисовать стандартный ajax через jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, простым способом передать параметры в `ActionLink` не получится, все решения будут похожи на то, которое вы привели в вопросе.

Мне кажется, проще будет использовать обычную форму:

```
<!-- здесь блоки с папками и файлами -->

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MoveToFolder", new AjaxOptions())) {
    <input type="hidden" name="ID_Folder" id="ID_Folder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ID_File" id="ID_File" />
    <input type="submit" value="Переместить в папку" />
}
```

(Форма будет отправляться методом `Post`, поставьте над action атрибут `[HttpPost]`, либо укажите в `AjaxOptions` метод `Get`)

Если вам требуется именно ссылка для отправки формы, то используйте что-то вроде:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;">Переместить в папку</a>
```

Предполагаю, что у вас есть обработчики выбора пользователем папки и файла. В нем устанавливаем значения соответствующих скрытых полей, примерно так:

```
$('.dirs').on('click', function () {
    var currentFolderId = $(this).data('id');
    $('#ID_Folder').val(currentFolderId);
});

$('.files').on('click', function () {
    var currentFileId = $(this).data('id');
    $('#ID_File').val(currentFileId);
});
```

Также не забудьте подключить nuget `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` и скрипт `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`.